# What is a token in a TokenCredential in @azure/storage-blob, and how do I acquire one?

Tags: javascript, azure, browser, azure-blob-storage

I am using a Storage Account for Blobs.
I am exposing a SPA web application that acts acts as an online file manager for the blobs in the storage account.

I am using @azure/storage-blob

I want to be able to circumvent usage of an Azure Function to generate SAS-tokens, and SharedKey credentials are only for server-side. This leaves only **TokenCredential** as a means of authorization.

What I've tried:
I've tried to register my web app in App Registration, and allowed it "user_impersonation" for Storage Accounts. I then used MSAL to first login the user, and then silently acquire an accesstoken.

My assumption was that this would work as a token for the TokenCredential, but it does not for me.

Has anyone tried this themselves?
Thanks,
Rasmus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By reviewing the `@azure/storage-blob` SDK, for `BlobServiceClient`, there is a constructor

```
  constructor(
    url: string,
    credential?: StorageSharedKeyCredential | AnonymousCredential | TokenCredential,
    options?: StoragePipelineOptions
  );
```

As you are developing a SPA, you may use `InteractiveBrowserCredential` in `@azure/identity`

```
  var interactiveBrowserCredential = new InteractiveBrowserCredential("tenant_id, e4c9ab4e-****-****-****-230ba2a757fb", "client_id,ebb50468-****-****-****-85e7968135c0");
  const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
    `https://${account}.blob.core.windows.net`,
    interactiveBrowserCredential
  );
```

---

**By the way, you need to assign necessary storage role for a use before him accessing storage with AAD token.**

[image]

Comment: Okay I will try this when I get home today. And do I still need to have my web app registered as an App Registration with storage account 'user_impersonation' permissions enabled? Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I finally managed to solve this problem. The fault was somewhere in my storage account permissions, my msal implementation, or mock calls from postman. Regardless, it works, and I noted my steps of progress. Thanks for your help :)